# Add Click event listener to dynamically inserted element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have form that saved in a string and I need submit it.

In component I create div with `display:none` and then set it `innerHTML` to string with form.

```
<div class="form" #form [innerHTML]="formInnerHTML"></div>
```

---

```
 @ViewChild('form')
 form: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;


 this.formInnerHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(response.htmlForm);
 this.form.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].click(); //Issue here, cannot read click of undefined
```

The form is submitted when I click on third input.

But the issue is that `this.form` that is ElementRef not updates. When I make console log  of it before invoking `click()` I dont see any child html elements in it.

What should I do? Or maybe there are some other approaches?

Comment: Here it says that the `this.form.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[2]` is undefined and that's why the click cannot be handle.
Check if you are calling the right class of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by myself. Solution:

I have added `ChangeDetectorRef` in my component and after setting innerHTML I call `detectChanges` method.

```
 this.formInnerHTML = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(response.htmlForm);
 this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); //Added
```

Actually I dont know why sometimes I should make this `detectChanges`. If anyone know, please explain.